# How to configure network interface names booting from read only medium?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, boot, udev, upstart

in a Ubuntu 12.04 system, we'd like to configure the names of the (physical) network interfaces (such as eth0, eth1, ...) using udev rules such as those generated in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. While the boot medium is read only, we still want to be able to persistently (re)configure these rules for future boots (e.g. after a network card has been replaced). For persistency, we'd like to store the rules to a (writeable) local hard disk (different from the read only boot medium).

The problem appears to be, how to inform udev early enough about the stored rules: Apparently, this can't happen before the local hard disk with the stored rules is mounted. Mounting the disk depends on udev recognizing the local hard disk device. At the same time, udev also recognizes network interfaces and triggers their configuration (potentially before the rules from the local hard disk would be in effect).

How would the required initializations be coordinated correctly during boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our current solution, using three new upstart jobs, appears to work (please comment):

1. We use a new upstart task `/etc/init/hold-interfaces.conf` to delay the configuration of network interfaces (in upstart jobs `/etc/init/network-interface.conf`) until the stored network rules have been installed (into `/etc/udev/rules.d/71-persistent-net.rules`, where `/etc/` was overlaid during `initrd/init` with a `tmpfs` for writeability).

   ```
   # /etc/init/hold-interfaces.conf

   start on starting network-interface and started mark-configured

   instance holding${INTERFACE:+/}${INTERFACE:-}

   task

   exec :
   ```

   - The `start on` condition requires `starting network-interface`. This is the usual method to prohibit an upstart job from starting without modifying the existing job file (in this case `/etc/init/network-interface.conf`), cf. [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-before-another-job).
   - As there will be separate instances of the `network-interface` job (one for each interface), there must also be corresponding instances of `hold-interfaces`. Hence, the `instance` declaration (similar to the one found in `/etc/init/network-interface-security.conf`).
   - The `start on` condition also requires `started mark-configured`. This signals that the network rules have been updated and initialization of the interfaces is allowed to continue. It is not possible to directly wait for an upstart event to be emitted: Such an event would only allow a single instance of `hold-interfaces` to continue. The recommended workaround is to simulate some kind of persistent event using a dedicated upstart job, in this case `/etc/init/mark-configured.conf` (Cf. [LP: #447654](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/447654)).
2. The new upstart job `/etc/init/mark-configured.conf` provides a persistent indication that all network configuration files have been updated:

   ```
   start on network-rules-ready

   task

   exec :
   ```

   - A single event `network-rules-ready` is sufficient to start this job. After that, the job `mark-configured` is known to be `started` which releases the waiting instances of `hold-interfaces` an consequently also those of `network-interface`.
3. The third new upstart job `/etc/init/configure_interfaces.conf` installs the network rules, stops the delayed `network-interface` jobs (since they may be started with configuration data from the old network rules), emits the releasing event and retriggers all udev events adding a network device.

   ```
   # /etc/init/configure_interfaces.conf

   start on local-filesystems

   task

   script
       find_and_mount_local_hard_disk # abbreviated
       install_stored_rules_and_other_network_configurations # abbreviated

       udevadm control --reload-rules

       # Stop all active network-interface upstart jobs (with data from old rules)
       stop_active_network_interface_jobs # abbreviated, using: initctl stop network-interface <interface>

       # Allow next network-interface jobs
       # (with data from stored rules) to complete.
       initctl emit --no-wait network-rules-ready

       # Trigger udev recognition.
       udevadm trigger --action='add' --subsystem-match='net'
   end script
   ```

On a test system (with three network interfaces), this appears to work. On the other hand, we are uncertain if it may not fail sometimes / at least on other systems:

1. Is there a guarantee that all local hard disk devices are available when `find_and_mount_local_hard_disk` is run?
2. Is there a race condition that may lead to some network devices not being recognized? (E.g.: Before reading the new udev rules, the kernel may pass a new device to udev such that it starts an upstart job `network-interface` using the old rules. It may take a while until upstart can recognize this job for stopping it. Is it possible that meanwhile the udev new rules can be loaded, stopping `network-interface` jobs misses the emerging job and the signal `network-rules-ready` is emitted such that the device would later be started still using the old attributes?)
3. How could the upstart jobs `/etc/init/network-interface-security.conf` be delayed / controlled suitably? Should other jobs or events be delayed / retriggered?

   - The jobs `/etc/init/network-interface-security.conf` should be delayed suitably, if the network configurations they are affected by are installed early enough (together with the network rules).
   - Also, if any of the held interfaces is configured as `auto` in `/etc/network/interfaces`, this delays the signal `static-network-up` (emitted by `/etc/network/if-up.d/upstart` after all `auto` interfaces are up). Thus, most network dependent jobs should be delayed suitably, including starting of SysV init scripts (triggered by `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`).
4. Other problems?

(Is there an easier way to delay the configuration of all network devices (and dependent startup tasks) via kernel, udev, upstart or other features until after the local hard disk is mounted and the new network rules are in effect?)